# why it is shown Undefined index error in the $_FILES["fname"]['name']; section?

Tags: php, arrays, undefined-index

```
    <?php 

$name= $_FILES['fname']['name'];
echo $name;


?>

<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype=" multipart/form-data">
    Select file: <br><br>

    <input type="file" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit"><br>


</form>
```

Comment: `<form method="POST" enctype=" multipart/form-data">
    Select file: <br><br>
    <input type="file" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit"><br>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['fname']['name'])){
 $name= $_FILES['fname']['name'];
 echo $name;
}
?>` check it and tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This file must be save as test.php     
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['formFile'])){
    $name= $_FILES['fname']['name'];
    echo $name;
    }
else{
echo "No file selected";
}

    ?>

    <form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file: <br><br>

        <input type="file" name="fname"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="formFile"><br>


    </form>
```

Comment: Yes, I've saved it as test.php
Now error (Undefined index ) is gone, but code isn't showing the name of the file that I've chosen

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data"                   in your own version you include a space

Comment: what is the format and the size of the file you try upload?

Comment: I tried a image file of size 215 kb and tried text file of size 3kb too. but the name of the file is not showing

Comment: It works perfectly on my machine. Please copy that code as it is and paste in ur code editor and save as a .php file. Not a .html file

Comment: i wish i can send you a screenshot

Comment: Thanks, now its working, 
I've saved it as a .php file.  but what is my mistake?

Comment: then mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$name= $_FILES['fname']['name'];
echo $name;
}
```

Comment: error (Undefined error ) is gone, but the code isn't showing the name of the file that I've chosen.